# Exchange crashed, backups failed, only mail is on my mobile (andriod) device, is it possible to move that data to Exchange Online?

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchangeonline

Bad weekend... I had a piece of hardware fail which spiked the power and took out my UPS which dropped my SAN and subsequently killed my Exchange 2010 server.  Then I found out that the Veeam backups I had been doing were not backing up exchange properly.  I was already planning on migrating to Exchange Online in another month but this kind of puts a little more priority on it.

During this process I discovered that my workstation's outlook was not caching my emails/contacts/calendar to a local PST.  However, my Android has at least the most recent 2 weeks of email and all of my calendar appointments.

I just got Exchange Online setup, is it possible to feed what is on my Android device back up to Exchange Online?

Comment: That's a series of cascading failures. But I'm pretty sure your Exchange system should have been recoverable.

Comment: Still working on it...  It's in Hyper-V and the server itself is corrupted (took forever just to even get into it)  And sfc can't complete either to fix it.  DISM doesn't work because it's on 2008r2.  So I barely have the server up.  The DB's seem to be in order now, but the OS is still corrupted (and exchange doesn't come online even though the DBs are ok).  I also can't install over the top either.  So yeah, it's a mess... I was hoping Veeam was a little better than this for accuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just got Exchange Online setup, is it possible to feed what is on my
> Android device back up to Exchange Online?

That's doubtful unless you can somehow export the email from your phone.

What you can do if you have access to the Exchange mailbox database (EDB file) is use a third party utility to export the mailbox contents, which can then be imported into your Exchange Online mailbox.

https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/Exchange-Server-Data-Recovery.html

https://www.edbmails.com/

https://www.stellarinfo.com/edb-exchange-server-recovery.htm

Comment: That's cheaper than I remember.  I only have a handful of accounts, definitely worth the money (especially considering I spent all weekend trying to recover this server). Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to your EDB files, Veeam comes with an Exchange Explorer that can export to pst, too.

Comment: If you have working EDB files, just reinstall Exchange in recover mode on a new server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it just got bumped to home page and I saw it only now.

If you have undamaged database files, you can simply reinstall Exchange on a new server (with the same OS, hostname and Exchange install path) using "recover server" mode.

Documentation is only currently available from Exchange Server 2016 onwards, but the option definitely existed in Exchange Server 2010 and 2013 too.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/high-availability/disaster-recovery/recover-exchange-servers